# How do I interpret these FTP file persmissions from the FTP client?

Tags: permissions, ftp, ftp-client

I've been tasked with debugging an automated process that gets a file from a vendor's FTP site outside our firewall.  My boss believes it's related to the file permissions of the file on the FTP server.

While logged into the FTP server with two different clients (Core FTP LE and the command line client that comes with Windows 7), the permissions for the file in question look like: -ART------TCP

I'm not sure how to interpret this format.  I've done searches, but they all come back with the standard unix type of file permissions (-rwxrwxrwx and using chmod to change them).

Can anyone point me to a guide on the file permissions format I'm seeing?  The 230 response tells me the following about the server: IBM Sterling Connect:Enterprise for UNIX

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A - a batch was added with CMU
R - requestable
T- transmitted
```

Have a look [here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/commerce/doc/mft/ceeunix/25/CEURemoteUserGuide25.pdf) page 23.